# What I need to do to get connected SQL Server data source with IIS (Local)?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, iis-10

I hosted .NET Core Web API in local IIS following these steps:

- Published the project into a file/folder location
- In IIS Manager, mapped the folder location

When I browse the site from IIS, it shows the default "WeatherForecast" (sample .NET model) fine. But, when I try to browse my developed page/controller it shows nothing(internal server error) Please note that, I am using datasource of SQL Server (locally) and using EF Core database first approach as ORM, and running from Visual Studio everything works fine.

I think, I need to point out my datasource anywhere during hosting in IIS or am I missing anything here?

I tried to use connection string in appsettings.json like below, but it didn't work

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBConnectionString": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TourActivityExpense;Trusted_Connection=True; "
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: `internal server error` might be anything, you need a stack trace.

Comment: I guessed that because, whenever I remove code that has DB Connection it runs fine, even from running visual studio, everything works fine :)

Comment: At least use a valid account to connect. If you don't know that inside/outside of VS the accounts are different, you should read https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 for hints.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `ConnectionStrings` like below, your issue should be fixed.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=XXX;Trusted_Connection=False;user id=XXX;pwd=XXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=true "
},
```